# Tools for tree diagram

Tags: diagrams, trees

I would like to make a simple scheme looking like tree diagram (structure like [this](http://www.conceptdraw.com/resources/images/solutions-screens/business/Root_Cause_Tree_Diagram_step4.png) or [that](http://bioweb.uwlax.edu/bio203/s2009/chamberl_case/Picture2.png)). The problem is that all the packages I did try, could make nice binary trees with little information in the nodes. My tree is not binary and I need to put some words on each node, so what tools could you recommend me to try for this?

Comment: somewhat related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50391/how-to-draw-a-horizontal-tree-with-branches-on-the-right-and-left. The second answer may be of interest to you.

Comment: There are lots of questions on the site with complex tree structures.  Have a look at [Joining two branches of a family tree](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/23241/2693) or
[How to draw up a hierarchical tree diagram for taxonomic classification](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/19029/2693) or
[Horizontal hierarchy tree in tikz-qtree: bad layout for longer node-names](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/41490/2693)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think TikZ can do that without problem and without library. It's possible to add some parameters if you want to change something automatically. You can with the next method to scale without problem.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style = {shape          = rectangle,
                                         rounded corners,
                                         fill           = blue!40!white,
                                         minimum width  = 3cm,
                                         minimum height = 1.5cm,
                                         align          = center,
                                         text           = white},
                   blue edge/.style  = { -,
                                         ultra thick,
                                         blue!40!white,
                                         shorten >= 4pt}]

% the nodes : possible  \newcommand*\dx{5} \newcommand*\dy{2}
\node(0;0) at (0,0) {Eukaryotes};
  \node(1;2)  at (5, 4) {Unikonts};   
  \node(1;1)  at (5, 2) {Chromalveolates}; 
  \node(1;0)  at (5, 0) {Excavates}; 
  \node(1;-1) at (5,-2) {Rhizaria}; 
  \node(1;-2) at (5,-4) {Plantae\\
                   (Archeplastida)};
     \node(2;1)  at (10,-2) {Conifers};
     \node(2;0)  at (10,-4) {Gnetales};
     \node(2;-1) at (10,-6) {Angiosperms};

% edges 
\foreach \j in {-2,...,2}
  { \draw[blue edge] (0;0.east) -- (1;\j.west); }
\foreach \j in {-1,...,1}
  { \draw[blue edge] (1;-2.east) -- (2;\j.west);}                  
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to modify the position with parameters:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style = {shape          = rectangle,
                                         rounded corners,
                                         fill           = blue!40!white,
                                         minimum width  = 3cm,
                                         minimum height = 1.5cm,
                                         align          = center,
                                         text           = white},
                   blue edge/.style  = { -,
                                         ultra thick,
                                         blue!40!white,
                                         shorten >= 4pt}] 

\newcommand*\dx{5} \newcommand*\dy{2} 
% nodes 
\node(0;0) at (0,0) {Eukaryotes};
  \node(1;2)   at (\dx, 2*\dy) {Unikonts};   
  \node(1;1)   at (\dx, \dy)   {Chromalveolates}; 
  \node(1;0)   at (\dx, 0)     {Excavates}; 
  \node(1;-1)  at (\dx,-\dy)   {Rhizaria}; 
  \node(1;-2)  at (\dx,-2*\dy) {Plantae\\
                               (Archeplastida)};
     \node(2;1)  at (2*\dx,-\dy)   {Conifers};
     \node(2;0)  at (2*\dx,-2*\dy) {Gnetales};
     \node(2;-1) at (2*\dx,-3*\dy) {Angiosperms};

% edges     
\foreach \j in {-2,...,2}
  { \draw[blue edge] (0;0.east) -- (1;\j.west); }
\foreach \j in {-1,...,1}
  { \draw[blue edge] (1;-2.east) -- (2;\j.west);}                  
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! I have almost finished my own diagram, however, compiler tells me that it doesn't know key 'tikz/align'. When I remove this line, everything works, but I cannot wrap a line. Could you help me with this?

Comment: If you work with pgf 2.00 you need to use `text centered` instead of 'align=center` but It would be preferable to install pgf 2.10.

Answer (score 4):

An example without coordinates. Run it with `xelatex` or `latex->dvips->ps2pdf`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-tree,array}    
\begin{document}
\def\PSB#1{\pspicture(3,1.5)\psTextFrame[shadow,fillcolor=red!30,
  fillstyle=solid,linecolor=blue,framearc=0.3](0,0)(3,1.5){%
    \shortstack{#1}}\endpspicture}

\pstree[treemode=R,levelsep=2cm]{\Tr[ref=rc]{\PSB{Eukaryotes}}}{%
  \Tr[ref=lc]{\PSB{Unikonts}}   
  \Tr[ref=lc]{\PSB{Chromalveolates}} 
  \Tr[ref=lc]{\PSB{Excavates}} 
  \Tr[ref=lc]{\PSB{Rhizaria}}
  \pstree[treemode=R,levelsep=4.5cm]{\Tr[ref=lc]{\PSB{Plantae\\(Archeplastida)}%
           \pnode(0,0.75){Dummy}{}}}{\def\pspred{Dummy}%
     \Tr[ref=lc]{\PSB{Conifers}}\def\pspred{Dummy}%
     \Tr[ref=lc]{\PSB{Gnetales}}\def\pspred{Dummy}%
     \Tr[ref=lc]{\PSB{Angiosperms}}%
  }}

\end{document}
```

[image]