# How to align parent nodes to the left/top in a tree

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees, tikz-qtree, qtree

I am drawing trees in LATEX. The `qtree` library seems to be what I need but the parent is always placed in the center of its children like this:

```
    parent
    /    \ 
child_1 child_2
```

(*I'm a new user and does not have enough reputation to post an image.*)

What I want is a right-growing tree like this:

```
root  -- child_1  -- grandchild_1_1
      \- child_2
      \- child_3  -- grandchild_3_1
                  \- grandchild_3_2 -- great-grandchild_3_2_1
      \- child_4  -- grandchild_4_1
```

Rotating the `qtree` to right-growing is insufficient since the parent nodes are then vertically aligned to the center of their children, but I need them to remain on the top of their subtrees.

I've tried `trees` library of TikZ, which allows customized "growth function" to specify the position of children. However it does not consider the size of subtrees, so in this case `child_4` would follow immediately under `child_3`, making `grandchild_4_1` overlap with `grandchild_3_2`.

Is there a simple way to just "disable" the centering of parents in `qtree`? Or is there any better solution (may be writing my own macro)?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You may have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). If you want, you can include your image, and remove the leading `!`. Then someone with enough reputation can edit it back in.

Comment: @mafp Thanks! I think plain text is fine :) What is the leading `!`?

Comment: If you include an image, the markup looks like `![description][link]`, there is a `!` in front of it. But now you have enough rep to do it yourself anyway, and your ASCII art explains it fine, indeed. Good question, btw.

Comment: Perhaps this is a duplicate question? [Horizontal hierarchy tree in tikz-qtree: bad layout for longer node-names](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/41490). And for a more complex version see: [How to draw a horizontal tree with branches on the right and left?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/50391). And for another version of a genealogical tree see [Joining two branches of a family tree](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/23241).

Comment: @AlanMunn No it's not. I've reviewed answers to these questions and although they talked about horizontal trees it seems that none of them provide the _alignment_ to left/top option - the parents are still center-aligned.

Comment: Ok, I think I see what you mean.  Let me take a stab at it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you want, but here's a solution using the `forest` package. It provides an alignment parameter for aligning the children of a node which does most of what you want.  I didn't know whether you wanted square edges or not, but they seem more appropriate for this kind of tree, (in the screen shot image the lines look odd, but this is an artefact of the screen rendering). I've added a simple alternative that looks a bit nicer without the squared edges.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}
\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
grow right/.style={for tree={%
  calign=last,
  grow=east,
  ,s sep=.5cm,
  parent anchor=east,
  child anchor=west,
  edge path={\noexpand\path[\forestoption{edge}] 
     (!u.parent anchor) -- +(0pt,-10pt) |- (.child anchor)
     \forestoption{edge label};}
  }
}
,grow right
[Root [Child1 ] 
      [Child2
         [GChild1 ]
         [Gchild2 ]
         [GChild3 ]
      ] 
      [Child3
         [Gchild4 ]
         [Gchild5 ]
      ]
]
\end{forest}
\hfill
\begin{forest}
[Root,for tree={calign=last,grow=east,draw, parent anchor=east,child anchor=west} [Child1 ] 
      [Child2
         [GChild1 ]
         [Gchild2 ]
         [GChild3 ]
      ] 
      [Child3
         [Gchild4 ]
         [Gchild5 ]
      ]
]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

**Edit:** Notice that the children are organized in a reversed order, due to the counter-clockwise coordinates. Using the options `calign=first, reversed=true` in the `for tree = {...}` block produces the exact tree needed, as shown below:

[image: order corrected]

Comment: Thanks! It works well (quite a new package, it wasn't in my repository before updated), and I've edited your answer to correct the ordering of child nodes after reading the manual.

Answer (score 3):

This is just a supplement to [Alan Munn's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/115429/) which uses the `edges` library and other features of the current version of Forest. This therefore requires version 2+.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt,multi,rgb]{standalone}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    grow'=0,
    parent anchor=children,
    child anchor=parent,
    anchor=parent,
    if n children=0{folder}{},
    edge path'={(!u.parent anchor) -- ++(5pt,0) |- (.child anchor)},
  },
  where n=1{
    calign with current edge
  }{},
  [Root
    [Child1]
    [Child2
      [GChild1]
      [Gchild2]
      [GChild3]
    ]
    [Child3
      [Gchild4 ]
      [Gchild5 ]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

This code produces the squared-edge version of the tree:

[image: squared edges]

I think the small offset at the start of the path, prior to the vertical line, looks a bit neater, but this could be eliminated if preferred by changing the definition of the edge path to

```
edge path'={(!u.parent anchor) |- (.child anchor)},
```

[image: squared edges without offset]

Alternatively, deleting this line altogether results in a tree using the default path:

[image: non-squared default edges]

Comment: GChild1 and GChild4 may not be aligned if Child2 and Child3 are of different length. How to align the third level with all other 3rd level elements?

Comment: @Akkumulator Does `tier` not work?