# Draw a counting tree with grow right and then placed on the right (or left) of page that shown on the picture

Tags: tikz-trees, forest, istgame

I need help about tikz (or any other latex tools) on how to draw a counting tree with grow right and then placed on the right (or left) of page that shown on the picture.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! What you try so far? Here on site are a lot of examples how to draw tree diagrams ...

Comment: Any news? You receive two answer, is any of them acceptable?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Custom horizontal tikz tree](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/315145/custom-horizontal-tikz-tree)

Answer (score 2):

This is only about how to draw the counting tree, using the [istgame](https://ctan.org/pkg/istgame) package:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
    
\usepackage{istgame}

\begin{document}

%% tree
\begin{istgame}[scale=.7,font=\scriptsize]
\tikzset{oval node/.style={ellipse node,draw=none}}
\setistgrowdirection'{east}
\xtdistance{14mm}{60mm}
\istrooto(A){start}   \istb \istb \istb \endist
\xtdistance{12mm}{20mm}
\istrooto(0)(A-1){0}  \istb \istb \istb \endist
\istrooto(1)(A-2){1}  \istb \istb \istb \endist
\istrooto(2)(A-3){2}  \istb \istb \istb \endist
\xtdistance{10mm}{10mm}
\istrooto(00)(0-1){0}
  \istb{}{0 \quad 2^03^07^0=1}
  \istb{}{1 \quad 2^03^07^1=7}
  \endist
\istrooto(01)(0-2){1}
  \istb{}{0}
  \istb{}{1}
  \endist
\istrooto(02)(0-3){2}
  \istb{}{0}
  \istb{}{1}
  \endist
\istrooto(10)(1-1){0}
  \istb{}{0}
  \istb{}{1}
  \endist
\istrooto(11)(1-2){1}
  \istb{}{0}
  \istb{}{1}
  \endist
\istrooto(12)(1-3){2}
  \istb{}{0}
  \istb{}{1}
  \endist
\istrooto(20)(2-1){0}
  \istb{}{0}
  \istb{}{1}
  \endist
\istrooto(21)(2-2){1}
  \istb{}{0}
  \istb{}{1}
  \endist
\istrooto(22)(2-3){2}
  \istb{}{0 \quad 2^23^27^0=36}
  \istb{}{1 \quad 2^23^27^1=252}
  \endist

\node [anchor=mid] at ([yshift=-1.3cm,xshift=-1.2cm]22) {a};
\node [anchor=mid] at ([yshift=-1.3cm]22) {b};
\node [anchor=mid] at ([yshift=-1.3cm,xshift=1.3cm]22) {c};
\end{istgame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank for your help. I already did this, the only thing that I don't is how to make the letters a b c at the bottom. Now you solve it completely, and I also learn about istgame (this is new for me) package in your solution, thank you very much. I hope I can solve at least one of another users qeustion.

Answer (score 2):

with `forest`

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{forest}
for tree = {font=\scriptsize,
            anchor=west,
            math content,
            grow'=0,
            s sep=2mm,
            l sep=7mm
            }
[start
    [0
        [0  [0\quad {2^{0} 3^{0} 7^{0}=1}]
            [1\quad {2^03^07^1=7}]
        ]
        [1  [0] [1]
        ]
        [2  [0] [1]
        ]
    ]
    [1
        [0  [0] [1]
        ]
        [1  [0] [1]
        ]
        [2  [0] [1]
        ]
    ]
    [2, name=aux1
        [0  [0] [1]
        ]
        [1  [0] [1]
        ]
        [2, name=aux2  
            [0\quad {2^{2}3^{2}7^{0}=36}] 
            [1\quad {2^{2}3^{0}7^{1}=252}, name=aux3]
        ]
    ]
]
\node (a) [below,xshift=5pt]   at (aux3.south west)   {c};
\node               at (aux2 |- a)   {b};
\node               at (aux1 |- a)   {a};
   \end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

For placement in your document you need first to show an example (with dummy text) of your document. It should be simple with inserting figures with above image on the right place in it.

Comment: Thank for your solution via forest, thank you